# JavaFX task not reruning once canceled or finishing once

Tags: multithreading, javafx, task

I am working on a basic Java FX task exercise. It counts from 1 to 150 on a thread. The current value is presented on a label and updates a progress bar.

There is a button to start the task, to cancel it and to view canceled status of the task.

The thing that puzzles me is as to why I cannot re run the task after having canceled the thread once(same thing happens if I let the task finnish).

I want to be able to rerun the task . Then I need to make it so that it will resume(though that shouldn't be that hard after  figuring out how to rerun the task)

Source ;

```
public class JavaFX_Task extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final Task task;
    task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            int max = 150;
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
                updateProgress(i, max);
                updateMessage(String.valueOf(i));

                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

    Label labelCount = new Label();
    labelCount.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

    final Label labelState = new Label();

    Button btnStart = new Button("Start Task");
    btnStart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

             new Thread(task).start();


        }
    });

    Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel Task");

    btnCancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            task.cancel();

        }
    });

    Button btnReadTaskState = new Button("Read Task State");
    btnReadTaskState.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            labelState.setText(task.getState().toString());
        }
    });


    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    vBox.setSpacing(5);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(
            progressBar, 
            labelCount,
            btnStart,
            btnCancel,
            btnReadTaskState, 
            labelState);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(vBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The [`Task` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) is pretty clear on this.

> As with [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), a `Task` is a one-shot class and cannot be reused. See [`Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) for a reusable [`Worker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html).

There is an example of restartable concurrent services in the Service documentation.